# Cross Reference An Input Element's Value Attribute Against An Array Of Objects

Tags: javascript, json, loops, asynchronous, fetch-api

I have some JSON data that is a series of objects inside an array that is fetched and outputted via PHP `json_encode()` and the javascript `fetch()` API. Essentially it is outputting specific image board data where you can have the same image on multiple boards and, obviously, multiple image boards. This all works as expected.

An example of this data is:

```
[
    {board_id: 428, board_name: 'tree board', image_id: 269}
    {board_id: 428, board_name: 'tree board', image_id: 292}
    {board_id: 426, board_name: 'Urban and City', image_id: 269}
    {board_id: 426, board_name: 'Urban and City', image_id: 292}
    {board_id: 426, board_name: 'Urban and City', image_id: 410}
    {board_id: 365, board_name: 'random stuff', image_id: 269}
    {board_id: 365, board_name: 'random stuff', image_id: 292}
]
```

**The Context**

Within a `then()` method of the JavaScript `fetch()` API some button elements are created based on the above data and appended to a parent wrapper, where only one element is created per `board_id` value. It only creates one button per `board_id` because each board name only needs to be shown once.

```
// data fetched from the database with PHP and JS fetch()

const data=[{board_id:428,board_name:"tree board",image_id:269},{board_id:428,board_name:"tree board",image_id:292},{board_id:426,board_name:"Urban and City",image_id:269},{board_id:426,board_name:"Urban and City",image_id:292},{board_id:426,board_name:"Urban and City",image_id:410},{board_id:365,board_name:"random stuff",image_id:269},{board_id:365,board_name:"random stuff",image_id:292}];

// code that sits inside the .then() method of the fetch()

const wrapper = document.querySelector('.wrapper');

const ids = [];
const buttons = [];

for (const { board_id, board_name } of data) {
    if (!ids.includes(board_id)) {
        ids.push(board_id);
        buttons.push(`<button value=${board_id}>${board_name}</button>`);
    }
}

wrapper.innerHTML = buttons.join('');
```

This produces this HTML (**let's call this 'Component A'**):

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <button value="428">tree board</button>
    <button value="426">Urban and City</button>
    <button value="365">random stuff</button>
</div>
```

There is a separate component outputted onto the page via a loop on page load that holds individual images and related details.

Simplified HTML of the image forms (**let's call these 'Component B'**)

```
<form method="post">
    <img src="path/to/image.jpg">
    <input value="269" type="hidden" class="image-id">
    <p class="add-to-board">Add To Image Board</p>
</form>
```

When you click the 'Add to Image Board' element within this form it opens up the board component (Component A) and instigates the `fetch()` that outputs the list of board buttons.

**Note:** because this JSON data is only ever fetched once, a `.click()` event is passed from the 'Add To Image Board' `<p>` element to a separate form/button at the top of the page to make it more performant instead of having to run through what could potentially be a large number of image components etc.

The image component/form shown above contains a hidden input element that holds the `image_id` value in its `value` attribute.

You can then select which specific board (from 'Component A') that you wish to add the selected image to.

All of this works OK.

**The Problem**

What I am trying to do within the `then()` method of the `fetch()` that uses the JSON data is to check if the `image_id` of the selected image from the image component (Component B) is already allocated to a `board_id` in the JSON array of objects, and if so add a class name for styling purposes to the relevant button in 'Component A' e.g. `class="allocated"`

Although there is only one board component that shows the boards list (component A), there are multiple instances of the image component (Component B).

Below is some pseudo code to get the image_id from the image component (I have no idea how to get this to work in conjunction with, or inside an asynchronous `then()` method ??):

```
let addToBoard = document.querySelectorAll('.add-to-board')

addToBoard.forEach((i) => {
    i.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        e.target.closest('form).querySelector('.image-id').value
    })
})
```

**Question Summary**

How do I cross reference the `image_id` value from the image component (Component B) to check for an equivalent value in the JSON array of objects, and if it is present then output a class attribute on the related HTML button in Component A.

Any help hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Lookup in the array using `find`, and if it finds an entry, then use that to grab the `board_id` and search for the button you want to add the class on using an [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors).

Note in the lookup using `find`, you have to to turn the value attribute into a number since due to the HTML spec attributes can only be strings whilst in your data source it's a number.

```
const board = data.find(board => board.image_id === parseInt(e.target.closest('form').querySelector('.image-id').value))
if (board) {
    document.querySelector(`.wrapper button[value="${board.board_id}"]`).classList.add("your-class-to-add");
}
```